# Jupyter Notebook kernel error after installing ipykernel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, kernel

I installed Ipykernel along with pandas and PyTorch for a new environment in Anaconda. After the new environment was created and I added the new kernel to my jupyter notebook, I got this error.

```
  File "C:\Users\liuxinzh\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select
.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)

  File "C:\Users\liuxinzh\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython
\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing error: The specified module could n
ot be found.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Just installed and uninstalled pyzmq